# Custom formatting in viz Charts SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am building a sample map by following the [explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Bar/preview) example for bar chart. everything works fine in my project except for the custom formatting. In the sample, **CustomerFormat.js** is used as a file for custom label formatting on the value/category axis and it works fine there. when I try to implement the same in my project, formatting functions in the file are never called. It just returns the default value associated with the function[There is no issue with the path as the file is found and loaded in my console].

I am trying to call the formatting function as follows:

```
oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
                valueAxis: {
                    title: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    label:{
                        formatString: CustomerFormat.FIORI_LABEL_SHORTFORMAT_10                         
                    }
                }
            });
```

It make a call without error but instead of formatting the value it returns the hard coded string assigned to the function id
[image]

I am not sure what's going wrong. I tried putting a debugger inside the formatting function but it does not stop at the debug point.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue at last.

We need to register our custom format function first by calling the function "**registerCustomFormat**" in the customerformat.js file. Silly mistake!!!